# Multiply all elements of a column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe:

| Idx | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 5 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 3 | 0 |

I want to calculate the product of all elements in all columns. e.g.

```
- P_A =  2*1*3*2 = 12
- P_B = 5*2*1*3 = 30
- P_C = 1*2*1*0 = 0
```

Ideally, the result would be in a list format [P_A, P_B, P_C].

What is the most efficient way to compute this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
>>> df[['A', 'B', 'C']].prod().tolist()
[12, 30, 0]
>>>
```

Or:

```
>>> df.set_index('Idx').prod().tolist()
[12, 30, 0]
>>>
```

Or also:

```
>>> df.filter(regex='[^Idx]').prod().tolist()
[12, 30, 0]
>>>
```

Or with `iloc`:

```
>>> df.iloc[:, 1:].prod().tolist()
[12, 30, 0]
>>>
```

Or with `drop`:

```
>>> df[df.columns.drop('Idx')].prod().tolist()
[12, 30, 0]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `numpy.product`:

```
import numpy as np
np.product(df.set_index('Idx'))
```

output:

```
A    12
B    30
C     0
```

as list:

```
products = np.product(df.set_index('Idx')).to_list()
```